# How to optimize my face recognition program and make it faster?

Tags: python, performance, artificial-intelligence, gpu, face-recognition

i was working with face-recognition library in python but its so slow to recognize one face and i need it for multiple face .

i already tried face-recognition library this is what i did

```
import face_recognition
known_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("known.jpg")
unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("unknown.jpg")

known_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)[0]
unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]

results = face_recognition.compare_faces([known_encoding], unknown_encoding)
```

but it take a lot of time where i want to do it for thousands of faces , is there any way to do it faster ?  or should i run it on gpu ?

also will threading make a difference on the performance ?

Comment: Have you tried using any of the Keras examples? Take a look at this [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-perform-face-recognition-with-vggface2-convolutional-neural-network-in-keras/) and this other [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/keras-face-detection-recognition/)

Comment: thanks i ll try it out and see if it is faster

Comment: I don't think that you need to change your library, you have to check some variables that can impact in performance like: what the size of this images? which CPU/GPU are you using? Take a look at [this](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/71) thread on github

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use deepface. It covers Keras based face recognition models. My experiments show that VGG-Face is the fastest to build but predictions are almost same for all models.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
models = ["VGG-Face", "Facenet", "OpenFace", "DeepFace", "DeepID"]
pairs = [
   ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg"],
   ["img1.jpg", "img3.jpg"],
   ["img1.jpg", "img4.jpg"]
]
result = DeepFace.verify(pairs, model_name = models[0])
```

Comment: thanks which model is best among "VGG-Face", "Facenet", "OpenFace", "DeepFace", "DeepID"?